# Fill proxy form when PC is locked

Tags: selenium, http, vbscript, proxy

I need to enter a site for which a **proxy form** has to be filled. I couldn't get through the form using Selenium VBA.

I called a **VBS** script from **VBA** to fill the form. It works when the PC is **not locked.**

Below is the proxy form.

[image: Proxy form that has to be filled by VBS]

Outlook VBA code to call VBS:

```
Dim bot as new chromedriver

bot.Start "chrome", "https://nissan.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fhome.do%3F"

bot.Get ("https://nissan.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fhome.do%3F") '//load webpage

strFileName = "d:\LocalData\Z018439\Desktop\MY\NX-AMO\VBACodes\Shell.vbs"

Set oshell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

oshell.Run "vbsc " & strFileName '//call vbs file
```

VBS code to fill proxy form:

```
Sub test()
    Dim shell_object
    Dim app_path, time

    wscript.Sleep 12000

    shell_object = "wscript.shell"

    Set objshell = CreateObject(shell_object)

    objshell.SendKeys ""

    objshell.SendKeys "{Tab}"

    objshell.SendKeys ""

    objshell.SendKeys "{Enter}"

End Sub
```

When the PC is locked, keyboard function is disabled and hence sendkeys(VBS) is not working. Launch is done upon arrival of a new mail in Outlook.

How do I fill the proxy form when the **PC is locked.**

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for your feedback. I have done the corrections.

Comment: Well, The actual operation is to call VBS from VBA. Both part works well.Out of which, VBS part fills the form when pc is unlocked. But when PC is locked, keyboard function is disabled and hence sendkeys(VBS) is not working. Launch is done upon arrival of a new mail in outlook. VBA which I mentioned above is Outlook VBA.